# Resolving 'net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT' Error After Upgrading Ruby to 3.2.2 and Rails to 7 with jsbundling Gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I upgraded Ruby from 2.7 to 3.2.2 and Rails from 6 to 7, I encountered this error:

`GET https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-rum-1.248.0.min.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

I have upgraded Webpack using the jsbundling gem. Could you please suggest how to resolve this error? Also, should I consider switching to the importmap gem instead of jsbundling?

Comment: That is an error of your web browser, telling you that it blocked the download of the JavaScript resource. This is likely caused by an ad-blocker or another content blocker you may have installed in your webbrowser. It is unrelated to an update of Ruby or Rails.